# Does umrah expiate all types of sins?

Tags: umrah

Does performing one umrah remove all types of sins?
How many times should one perform an umrah?

Answer (score 0):

Performing Umrah (or Hajj) doesn't cleanse you of sins. The only way you can cleanse yourself of your sins is when you repent sincerely and decide not to repeat them. 
But if your sins are those where you have wronged someone, then unless you seek repentance from that person and compensate him for your wrong doings, you won't be able to cleanse yourself of your sins.

Comment: Performing hajj does erase sins as stated in [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1521) hadith and [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim:121) hadith.

Comment: And there are also ahadith that Umrah expiates sins such as [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1773) and [this](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2887) and [this](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2892).